# Delphi - Icon of compiled EXE is wrong and cannot be changed

Tags: delphi, resources, icons, delphi-xe4

I'm having this strange issue for the first time in my 15+ experience of using Delphi.
This is the icon I set in the project options (XE4):
[image]

And this is the resulting application icon after compiled:

[image]

I've no idea where does that icon come from and I have **no way to change the icon** (really driving me crazy).

The icon of this project has been ok for over a year until later today. Things I've tried with **no luck**:

- Use the 'Load Icon...' button to change it to another complete different icon and re-build.
- Use the 'Default' button to reset to default icon and re-build.
- Deleted `project1.res` file and re-build.
- Deleted the `.dproj` file, open `.dpr` file instead and let the Delphi IDE created a blank new `.dproj` file. no luck.
- I thought it's the Windows 7's `IconCache.db` file corrupted, deleted that file and restarted Windows, no help. Actually I used Resource Hacker to confirmed it's not the Windows Explorer displaying the wrong icon but it's the icon resource in the EXE is wrong... too strange.
- restored the `.dproj` file from SVN to yesterday(the icon was ok yesterday)'s revision and no luck.

Anything else do you suggest me to try? Thank you!

Comment: The main icon is the one whose name appears first when sorted in alphabetical order. Inspect the exe with a resource jacker and see which icon that is. It probably comes from code you recently added.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Resource Hacker shows that there are only 3 icons in the EXE, and all are the same, screenshot: https://screenpresso.com/=MIPyg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Review the line in your main form with `{$R *.res}`. I had the same issue and it was that this line was accidentally deleted. That caused that icon and other resouces to not be correct in the final executable, like version number, icons etc.

If you don't know what that line is, simply make a few empty new vcl application and search it in the main form.

Comment: Do you mean `{$R *.dfm}`? It's present in the main form's `.pas` file.

Comment: Ah yes you are right Diego! The `{$R *.res}` directive is missing from the `.dpr` project source file, adding it back solved the issue!  Maybe I'm too exhausted today ;) Thank you Diego, David and thank you stackoverflow! I love the Delphi community :)

Comment: Your revision control system would have revealed this